# Find and delete duplicate Entries in an embedded Array

Tags: mongodb

I got the below illustrated JSON in my MongoDB. I got several hundred entries. The issue is that a few of them have multiple entries within the embedded array. In this illustration the entry_2 and the following entry_2 object of the array type are not allowed. I want to delete one of the two objects where the name of type array is of value "entry_2".

```
{   
   "id": null,
   "name": "",
   "array" [
       {
             "name": "entry_1"
       },
       {
             "name": "entry_2"

       },
       {
             "name": "entry_2"

       },
       {
             "name": "entry_3"

       }
   ]
}
```

Hence, my JSON should look like the following after the Query:

```
{   
   "id": null,
   "name": "",
   "array" [
       {
             "name": "entry_1"
       },
       {
             "name": "entry_2"

       },
       {
             "name": "entry_3"

       }
   ]
}
```

I tried to browse SO and read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#exact-match-on-the-embedded-document but I couldn't get a solution.

---

**-- EDIT --**

I have to use the option { allowDiskUse: true } and don't know how to implement it in the query. Furthermore, I tried to adjust the query to my certain use case, where I got the following structure:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "556ccf6f59bbda5ea20a8884"
},
"id": 1159,
"description": "Cheese, goat, soft type",
"tags": [],
"manufacturer": "",
"group": "Dairy and Egg Products",
"portions": [
    {
        "unit": "oz",
        "grams": 28.35,
        "amount": 1
    }
],
"nutrients": [
    {
        "description": "Protein",
        "group": "Composition",
        "value": 18.52,
        "units": "g"
    },
    {
        "group": "Composition",
        "value": 21.08,
        "units": "g",
        "description": "Total lipid (fat)"
    },
    {
        "description": "Protein",
        "group": "Composition",
        "value": 18.52,
        "units": "g"
    }
    ]
}
```

Based on the answer below I tried:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$unwind": "$nutrients"
    },
    {
       "$group": {
           "_id": "$_id",
           "id": { "$first": "$id" }
           "description": { "$first": "$description" },
           "tags" : { "$first": "$tags" },
           "manufacturer" : { "$first": "$manufacturer" },
           "group" : { "$first": "$group" },     
           "portions" : { "$first": "$portions" },
           "nutrients": {
               "$addToSet": "$nutrients"
           }        
       }
    }
],
options = { "allowDiskUse": true };
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, options);
```

I get the error message: "unexpected String".
I suppose it has something to do with the "_id" object an "tags" array.

Comment: You are getting the error because your pipeline is missing a comma `,` after the `"id": { "$first": "$id" }` expression in the `$group` operator expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$reduce`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to remove the duplicates in the array as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $addFields: {
        array: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$array",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $in: ["$$this.name", "$$value.name"] }, 
                        "$$value",
                        { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62fdfdbf78a49d8782851482)

---

For older versions of MongoDB, use the following:

Try the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator, an [accumulator operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#aggregation-accumulator-operators) available only in the **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage. This will add an array of all unique values that results from applying an expression to each document in a group of documents that share the same group by key:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$array" },
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        array: { $addToSet: "$array" },
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "id": { "$first": "$id" }
    } }
])
```

The output is the desired array with the object:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5570a775d41ac325b8cb9a5f"),      
            "id": null,
            "array" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "entry_3"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "entry_2"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "entry_1"
                }
            ],
            "name" : ""
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

-- **EDIT** --

To set `allowDiskSpace` to true, the **[`aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** methods allows a second parameter for options like that. For example, with the above pipeline, you could do something like this:

```
var pipeline = [
    { $unwind: "$array" },
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        array: { $addToSet: "$array" },
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "id": { "$first": "$id" }
    } }
    ],
    options = { "allowDiskUse": true };

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, options);
```

Comment: I have to set allowDiskSpace to true. But I'm not sure on how to do this in the above query.

Comment: @user1772306 I've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: @chirdam Thank you, I updated the question accordingly. I think I'm close to a solution. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Does this delete the duplicate record? or just selected the first in duplicates?